# remote wmi connection c# - invalid parameter error

Tags: c#, wmi, remote-access

when i run the following code

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
        options.EnablePrivileges = true;
        options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
        options.Authority = "ntdlmdomain:InsTIL.com";
        options.Username = "instil" + @"\" + "admin";
        options.Password = "Pwd";

        ManagementScope scope= new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\172.16.2.171\root\cimv2"),options);
        scope.Connect();
        if (scope.IsConnected == true)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Connection Succeeded");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection Failed");
        }


        ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("Select * from win32_operatingsystem");
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

        ManagementObjectCollection querycollection = searcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject mobj in querycollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Computer name: {0}", mobj["csname"]);
            Console.WriteLine("Windows Directory : {0}", mobj["WindowsDirectory"]);
            Console.WriteLine("Operating System: {0}", mobj["Caption"]);
            Console.WriteLine("Version: {0}", mobj["Version"]);
            Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer : {0}", mobj["Manufacturer"]);
        }
```

i get following error

```
  Unhandled Exception: System.Management.ManagementException: Invalid parameter
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
    at System.Management.ManagementScope.InitializeGuts(Object o)
   at System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize()
  at remote_wmi.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\.net prep\.net examples\remote wmi\remote wmi\Program.cs:line 21
```

please help me to know why its happening.? what's wrong in this code? is we need to do any thing before executing this code? if yes, please specify it .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line is line 21?

Comment: @phonicUK: scope.connect();

Comment: Is the service account of type a network service?

Comment: @DarrenDavies: i am sorry, i don't know how to check that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did the following changes then i got an answer.

1) i haven't specified the domain name with user name.
 `options.Username = "admin";` instead of  `options.Username = "instil" + @"\" + "admin";`

2) 
`options.Authority = "ntlmdomain:InsTIL.com";` instead of `options.Authority = "ntdlmdomain:InsTIL.com";`

Comment: I got bit by the `ntdlmdomain` issue, too. Microsoft hasn't fixed that typo in their API docs yet.