# WMI connection error C#

Tags: c#, wmi

```
using System;
using System.Management;

public class Class1
{
    public static void Main()
    { 
        string strComputer = string.Format(@"machineName.domainname\root\cimv2");
        ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
        options.EnablePrivileges = true;
        options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
        options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
        options.Authority = "ntlmdomain:InsTIL.com:InsTIL.com";
        options.Username = "usr";
        options.Password = "pwd";

        ManagementScope oMs = new ManagementScope(strComputer, options);

        SelectQuery query =new SelectQuery("Select * From Win32_Directory Where Name ='"+string.Format(@"C:\Scripts")+"'");
        ManagementObjectSearcher oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oMs,query);
        ManagementObjectCollection oReturnCollection = oSearcher.Get();

        if (oReturnCollection.Count < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Folder does not exist");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Folder does exist");
        }

    }
}
```

I'm trying to connect to remote machine and checking existence of folder.But I'm getting below mentioned error.

I tried and incorporated changes discussed in [remote wmi connection c# - invalid parameter error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496561/remote-wmi-connection-c-sharp-invalid-parameter-error)

Program abruptly stops working and throws below error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Management.ManagementException: Invalid parameter
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStat
us errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementPath.CreateWbemPath(String path)
   at System.Management.ManagementPath..ctor(String path)
   at Class1.Main()
```

Comment: Why are you using string.format without any parameters? What line exactly do you get this error on? Are there any inner exceptions?

Comment: Also your NTLM domain isn't going to be the same as the one from that question, so I'd avoid using the NTLM domain if you aren't on a domain, or at least use the right one.

Answer (score 1):

You need backslashes before your machine name.  Change this:

```
string strComputer = string.Format(@"machineName.domainname\root\cimv2");
```

to this:

```
string strComputer = string.Format(@"\\machineName.domainname\root\cimv2");
```